# How do you find what class is keeping a network connection open?

Tags: .net, networking, connection

I'm accessing a database in steps, and making sure that I dispose of all my `DbConnection` objects & related when I've done with them; however, when all the network stuff is done & should all be closed I still find open network connections from the app on `netstat`. How do I find out what class instance is keeping these connections open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are calling the Close method on your connection, the *physical* connection doesn't necessarily get closed due to connection pooling.

Comment: Could you explain connection pooling in more detail?

Comment: Pooling is explained in detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx. It optimizes data access by keeping physical connections open because closing and opening them are expensive processes.